# Is iteration through a shared object thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, thread-safety, openmp

I have a parallel C++ algorithm that looks somewhat like this:

```cpp
void recursiveFunction(int p, std::unordered_set<int> localSet) {
    vector<someStruct> toCall;
    if (p > SOMEINT) {
        return;
    }
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) shared(localSet, someGlobalVector, someOtherGlobalVector)
    for (int i = 0; i < someGlobalVector[p].size(); ++i) {
        auto someLocalValue = someGlobalVector[p][i];
        auto someOtherLocal = someOtherGlobalVector[p][i];
        std::unordered_set<int> filtered;
        for (auto elem : localSet) {
            if (someLocalValue.count(elem) == 0) {
                filtered.insert(elem);
            }
        }
        if (checkSomeCondition(p+1, filtered)) {
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                tocall.push_back({someOtherLocal, filtered});
            }
        }
    }
    for (auto [elem1, elem2] : toCall) {
        recursiveFunction(p+1, filtered);
    }
}
```

Is iteration through a shared `unordered_set` thread safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is iteration through a shared unordered_set thread safe?

No, an `unordered_set` is not thread-safe by definition. However, this does not necessarily imply one's code has a *race condition* when using such structures; For instance, if one *only* reads the data structure, even concurrently, then one is on the safe side. This is the reason why truly immutable data structures are thread-safe by definition, because one cannot modify those structures, hence the name.

On the other hand, if the `unordered_set` is being modified concurrently by multiple threads then one has a *race condition*. Nonetheless, one can still write to a `unordered_set` in a thread-safety manner, as long as one ensures *mutual exclusion* when one performs does write.

Non-thread-safe data structures such as `unordered_set` rely upon the code accessing them to ensure *mutual exclusion* when currently modifying those structures by multiple threads.

To avoid *race conditions*, one can use the OpenMP's `critical` constructor to synchronize the accesses to the shared structure during the `insert` operation:

```
#pragma omp critical
{
  // the code to insure mutual exclusion.
}
```

However, that would slow down the parallelization due to the overhead of such a synchronization mechanism. Alternatively, one can create data structures that will only be accessed individually by each thread, insert into those structures, and have the *main* thread merge those structures into one (outside the parallel region).

Let us break down your code a bite:

```
void recursiveFunction(int p, std::unordered_set<int> localSet) {
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) shared(localSet, someGlobalVector, someOtherGlobalVector)
    for (int i = 0; i < someGlobalVector[p].size(); ++i) {
        auto someLocalValue = someGlobalVector[p][i];
        auto someOtherLocal = someOtherGlobalVector[p][i];
        std::unordered_set<int> filtered
        for (auto elem : localSet) {
            if (someLocalValue.count(elem) == 0) {
                filtered.insert(elem)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `localSet`, `someGlobalVector`, `someOtherGlobalVector` are shared, but they are only read. Hence, as long there is no other thread outside this method (running at the same time) changing those structures, you are fine. The `vector<someStruct> toCall` is shared, and modified, but the modification happens within a critical constructor, therefore there is no *race condition* there.

To conclude, as it is, and assuming that there is no other thread modifying the aforementioned shared structures, there is no *race-condition* in your code. Notwithstanding, you can profile your code to verify the overhead of that `critical` region. If the overhead is too high, you can try the following:

```
void recursiveFunction(int p, std::unordered_set<int> localSet, int total_threads) {
    vector<someStruct> thread_tocall[total_threads];
    vector<someStruct> toCall;
    if (p > SOMEINT) {
        return;
    }
    #pragma omp parallel shared(localSet, someGlobalVector, someOtherGlobalVector)
    {
        int thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();
        for (int i = 0; i < someGlobalVector[p].size(); ++i) {
             auto someLocalValue = someGlobalVector[p][i];
             auto someOtherLocal = someOtherGlobalVector[p][i];
             std::unordered_set<int> filtered;
             for (auto elem : localSet) {
                 if (someLocalValue.count(elem) == 0) {
                    filtered.insert(elem);
                 }
             }
           if (checkSomeCondition(p+1, filtered)) {
                thread_tocall[thread_id].push_back({someOtherLocal, filtered});
            }
         }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < total_threads; i++)
       for (auto [elem1, elem2] : thread_tocall[i]) {
          recursiveFunction(p+1, filtered);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If global object is pre-populated and only read then - then yes, it is typically thread safe. But if shared object can be modified while someone reads it - then read also becomes not thread safe.